# How can I enforce vertical alignment of GTK widgets across containers?

Tags: gtk

I'm using PyGTK on Windows to develop a small application.

How can I enforce vertical alignment of widgets across containers to achieve something like this?

[image: Mockup showing vertical alignment of widgets in separate gtk.Frames]

In the mockup, widgets are in separate frames, but I want to maintain vertical alignment as if they were in the same `gtk.Table`. If I put them in the same table then I can't put a `gtk.Frame` around the groups of widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's already too late for you, but for other people that find this question. You can create an array of SizeGroup with 8 elements, and add to each element every widget that should go on the same column, this will make the width of each cell on the respective grid to be the same size, if all widgets are added, this will have the side effect of also align them vertically. Just be sure the amount of columns in the grid below is the same as above.

Also, if your labels need some special alignment there is currently a bug that does not let you use halign and valign when using SizeGroup, see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733981 .